# Ubuntu 20.04 desktop pxe boot fails with no live file system on network

Tags: linux, pxe-boot, ubuntu-20.04

I have configured a ubuntu20 desktop pxe boot using nfs but it stops saying unable to find a live filesystem on the network, but ubuntu18 works fine in the same server can anyone help me.let me know if any info required

```
default vesamenu.c32 
 label install1
 menu label ^Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop 
menu default kernel ubuntu1804/vmlinuz 
append initrd=ubuntu1804/initrd boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.100.211>

label install2 
menu label ^Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop 
menu default kernel ubuntu20/vmlinuz 
append initrd=ubuntu20/initrd boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.100.211:/>

LABEL Ubuntu 20 LTS 
MENU LABEL Install Ubuntu 20 LTS KERNEL ubuntu20/vmlinuz # On PXE server, relative to TFTP Root INITRD ubuntu20/initrd
```

Comment: Have you verified you are using the correct kernel for network boot?

Also verify parameters, they seem to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are messing up NFS mountpoints here. Both Ubuntu 18 and Ubuntu 20 boot options point to the same path on your NFS server... This is my configuration:

`/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/ubuntu 192.168.xx.0/255.255.255.0(ro,sync,no_wdelay,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

The path `/srv/ubuntu` is the mountpoint of a ubuntu-20 iso in my case.

`pxelinux.cfg/default`:

```
DEFAULT menu.c32
MENU TITLE Server PXE Boot Menu
TIMEOUT 100

LABEL       Ubuntu
MENU LABEL  ^Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop
MENU DEFAULT
KERNEL     ubuntu-live/casper/vmlinuz
APPEND     root=/dev/nfs boot=casper ip=dhcp netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.xx.yy:/srv/ubuntu initrd=ubuntu-live/casper/initrd
```